# Jquery mobile losing formatting on a ul listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

This is my listview element:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="acceptedContent" data-theme="c">
</ul>
```

Create Process This works fine the first time through and the listview looks like its supposed to and appears to be working great:

```
$('#acceptedContent').append('<li><a href="#Info' + results.rows.item(i).infoID + '" data-transition="flow">' + results.rows.item(i).Info + '</a></li>');
```

I then call this to empty the div, it works and clears the div out:

```
$('#acceptedContent').empty();
```

Refresh the page with an ajax post, when i get data back I read it into the database then rebuild the pages. This list is the only page that loses it formatting. then I call the same function that I built the page up the first time with.

Rebuilding section 
The data is populated but I loose the formatting

```
$('#acceptedContent').append('<li><a href="#Info' + results.rows.item(i).infoID + '" data-transition="flow">' + results.rows.item(i).Info + '</a></li>');
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated ive been at it for what feels like days trying to figure this one out.

Ive tried the following along with mucking around with the order of execution but nothing got it to work, I put the following listview refresh after I made the append call in the rebuild section:

```
$("#acceptedContent").listview('refresh');
$("#acceptedContent ul").listview('refresh');
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: hi! could you post your JS code here? I mean the entire workflow where you're appending the list etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's how you do it :

You've got a listview like this :

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="acceptedContent" data-theme="c">
</ul>
```

You've got some data which you'll loop through and format as `<li/>`. Instead of appending multiple times, you could collect the `li` html in a variable and append it, only once :

```
var li = "";
//your loop, $.each, for or for..in
li += '<li><a href="#Info' + results.rows.item(i).infoID + '" data-transition="flow">' + results.rows.item(i).Info + '</a></li>';
//end of loop
```

So now, youve got all the data in one variable called `li`. Now how would you use this? Put it in the `<ul/>`

```
$('#acceptedContent').html(li);
```

This way you could cut down the use of `empty` and `append`. just use `html()` to erase and re-write.

**Now comes the important part.** You have to refresh the listview. You've got to use `listview("refresh")`, but not in the way you've done it. You have to *wait* for the `html()` to finish its work. Only then, must you use the `refresh` api, like this :

```
$('#acceptedContent').html(li).promise().done(function () {
   //refresh here - $(this) refers to ul here
   $(this).listview("refresh");
});
```

You've got some buttons in there. Just in case you can refresh those using the `trigger` method. So your code would look like this :

```
$('#acceptedContent').html(li).promise().done(function () {
   //refresh here - $(this) refers to ul here
   $(this).listview("refresh");
   //causes a refresh to happen on the elements such as button etc. WHICH lie inside ul
   $(this).trigger("create");
});
```

**Note :**
If you get this error

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'.

Change

```
$(this).listview("refresh");
```

to

```
$(this).listview().listview("refresh");
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:
07-25 14:28:49.598: D/CordovaLog(9579): Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'.

Comment: Crap now I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery191008186558447778225' of undefined

Comment: On the plus side, I did find something that google has nothing on "'jQuery191008186558447778225" take note of the time and date.

Comment: can u make a fiddle for ur problem?

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay hunger my fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/XxScottxX/89DqM/ everything works fine on the fiddle I guess it is another issue within my code :-/.

Comment: I got it working somehow. I did use  $(this).listview("refresh"); and the  $(this).trigger("create");. I put it at the end of my function and have it fire off when the refresh button is pressed. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
$('div[data-role=page]').page('destroy').page();
```

I use it like this:

```
$("someid").ajaxStop(function(){
 $('div[data-role=page]').page('destroy').page();
});
```

This rebuilds my css nicely.

Comment: The page method is deprecated buddy. (Unless OP is using an ancient jQM version). You must refresh using `trigger("create")`

Comment: @hungerpain you're right, I have not realized that and yes, I am running older version of jQuery Mobile. Thanks.